# What is vanilla Ubuntu called?

Tags: software-installation

What is vanilla, plain, default Ubuntu called?

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Unsurprisingly, Ubuntu is called Ubuntu. There is no trick here.

Comment: "Vanilla" means without modification to the regular installation. Nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just called Ubuntu, sometimes together with the "vanilla", "plain" or "default" attributes you used as well to make sure you mean the default and not any of the Ubuntu flavours like Kubuntu, Xubuntu and so on. There is no special other name for it though.

In case you were trying to ask about the name of the desktop environment used by the "default" Ubuntu, that would be Unity until release 17.04 and GNOME again since 17.10.